# C programing - function reads 10lines from text file and waits till you enter a latter loop

Tags: c, file, line

I got an assiment to make a function that reads and shows 10lines from text file
and stops and waits for you to enter anykey and then reads another 10lines till it gets to the end..

this is what I did

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * source;
    char sentence[80];

    source = fopen("source.txt", "r");


    while (fgets(sentence, 80, source) != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            fgets(sentence, 80, source);

            printf("%s", sentence);
        }


        printf("\n\n\n Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");


        while (getch() != NULL)
        {



            break;
        }

    }puts("\n\n\n .....DONE!!");

    fclose(source);

}
```

the problem with my function is that it repeats the last sentence multiple time
cuz of the for loop.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(sentence, 80, source) != NULL) //Breaks when fgets fails to read
{
    i++;
    printf("%s", sentence);
    if(i == 10) //10 lines read and printed
    {
        printf("\n\n\n Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        i = 0;  //Reset counter
        getch(); //Wait for key press
    }
}
```

If you want to wait until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(sentence, 80, source) != NULL) //Breaks when fgets fails to read
{
    i++;
    printf("%s", sentence);
    if(i == 10) //10 lines read and printed
    {
        printf("\n\n\n Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        i = 0;
        while(getch() != 13); //Keep looping until enter is pressed
    }
}
```

---

Another way to avoid resetting the value of `i` as [@LPs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436922/lps) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259109/c-programing-function-reads-10lines-from-text-file-and-waits-till-you-enter-a/30259170#comment48618154_30259170) is:

```
int i = 0;
while (fgets(sentence, 80, source) != NULL) //Breaks when fgets fails to read
{
    i++;
    printf("%s", sentence);
    if(i % 10 == 0) // Same as `if(! (i % 10))` 
    {
        printf("\n\n\n Press [Enter] key to continue.\n");
        while(getch() != 13); //Keep looping until enter is pressed
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Always check the return value of `fopen` to see if it was successful. `fopen` returns `NULL` on failure.

Comment: You can avoid to reset `i=0` by modifying the `if (i==0)` with `if (!(i%10 ))`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this getch function but what I generally do for waiting an enter key press is simply the following :

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

but it has a problem if you use scanf as scanf let the last enter pressed in the buffer.

edit : cool guy answer is way better !